# Why is my tracks array empty in my presentational component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working on this bug for a few hours now, and I think I've narrowed it down to these pieces of code:

// my track detail container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TrackDetail from './track_detail';
import { selectTracksFromPlaylist } from '../../reducers/selectors';

const mapStateToProps = (state, { playlistId }) => ({
  tracks: selectTracksFromPlaylist(state, state.entities.playlists[playlistId])
});
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrackDetail);

// my track detail presentational component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TrackIndexItem from './track_index_item';

const TrackDetail = ({ tracks }) => (
  <ul>
     { tracks.map(track => <TrackIndexItem key={track.id} track={track} />) }
  </ul>
);

export default TrackDetail;
```

// my selector that I'm using to select all tracks from a playlist:

```
export const selectTracksFromPlaylist = (state, playlist) => (
  playlist.track_ids.length > 0 ? playlist.track_ids.map(id => state.entities.tracks[id]) : [] 
);
```

// the component that's rendering my `TrackDetail`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import TrackDetail from '../track/track_detail_container';

class PlaylistDetail extends React.Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestSinglePlaylist(this.props.match.params.playlistId);
  }

  render() {
    const { playlist } = this.props;

    if (!playlist) return null;

    return (
      <div className="playlist-detail-container">
        <div className="playlist-detail-header">
          <p>Playlist</p>
          <h1>{ playlist.title }</h1>
          <p>
            Created by <span>{playlist.user}</span> • {playlist.track_ids.length} songs
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="playlist-detail-tracks">
          <TrackDetail playlistId={ playlist.id } />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PlaylistDetail;
```

This happens every time I try accessing the page normally (without physically doing a refresh; if I refresh the screen after this error pops up, it works):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: I disagree. If it were empty, the mapping would do nothing. Would you put down the code where the connected presentational component gets rendered?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll edit the post above. I've also changed a few minor things about the other code so I'll update that too!

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted. I guess the error is based on something undisclosed. I would start by checking that the initial state of your app contains empty variables to avoid errors (example, an empty array where an array is expected) and that your reducers populate the state with the correct data types. Do a lot of logging to check the data produced and if the incoming props are what they are supposed to be

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out! You're right; initially, my state had no tracks (it wasn't fetching any tracks/albums/artists hence the nil error). It was just fetching the playlists. :P